# ephemeral storage of Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have created new ec2 (m3-large) instance on Amazon with root partition 80GB.But mnt partition it automatically mounted with 30 GB.

Will the ephemeral  storage be charged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, ephemeral storage (mnt) is not charged but ephemeral storage will  not store  data permanent i.e. when you will stop your instance, ephemeral storage will be deleted, So only use ephemeral storage for temporary data.checkout this for more detail https://skeddly.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/1346918-ebs-backed-versus-instance-store

Comment: Not true when you reboot.  Ephemeral storage *survives* a reboot of the instance.  It does not survive a stop or a terminate.